# How simplify this css

Tags: html, css

I'm new in CSS. 
I create 4 class to change the style of each corner.
And is working as you can see in running codding snippet, but i repeat lot of code.

This is the only different line

> border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;

I would like to modify the css so I could create something like

```
<div id="infoPopup" class="note topRight">
```

I was trying something like

```
.note {}
.note:before {}
.note:before .topLeft {border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;}
.note:before .topRight {border-width: 0 0 16px 16px;}
.note:before .bottomLeft {border-width: 16px 16px 0 0;}
.note:before .bottomRight {border-width: 16px 0 0 16px;}
```

What I already have working

```css
    .noteTopRight {
        position: relative;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 1em 1.5em;
        margin: 2em auto;
        color: #fff;
        background: #97C02F;
    }

        .noteTopRight:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #658E15 #fff;
        }

    .noteTopLeft {
        position: relative;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 1em 1.5em;
        margin: 2em auto;
        color: #fff;
        background: #97C02F;
    }

        .noteTopLeft:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            border-width: 0 0 16px 16px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #658E15 #fff;
        }

    .noteBottomRight {
        position: relative;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 1em 1.5em;
        margin: 2em auto;
        color: #fff;
        background: #97C02F;
    }

        .noteBottomRight:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            border-width: 16px 16px 0 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #658E15 #fff;
        }

    .noteBottomLeft {
        position: relative;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 1em 1.5em;
        margin: 2em auto;
        color: #fff;
        background: #97C02F;
    }

        .noteBottomLeft:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            border-width: 16px 0 0 16px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #658E15 #fff;
        }
```

```html
<div class="noteTopRight"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div class="noteTopLeft"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div class="noteBottomRight"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div class="noteBottomLeft"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
```

Comment: First things first: `id`s are supposed to be unique so you need to fix that.  Then, you are allowed to combine classes so all the `divs` can be of the base class `.note` and then each one have a secondary class (like `.note-top-right` or `.note-top-left`) - Move the common attributes to the `.note` class and the different values to each of the other four classes.  Let me know if you need more details

Comment: @ochi You can see I try something like subclass. But the `:before` got me confused. Should I remove that  part from the subclass?

Comment: Sorry for the ID, that was just copy/paste to see if each class was working ok :)

Comment: There is no benefit to using `.note {}
.note:before {}`. You do not have to "initialize" selectors before using sub-selectors.

Comment: There are also some very good reasons for not changing what you have now. Using `.noteTopRight` is better than using `.note.topRight`, as the later  introduces styles to two very generic classes, while the former keeps all of your styling within a single specific class. This is why Bootstrap (for example)  uses classes like `.btn-lg` instead of `.btn.large`. It's better to restrict the classes you're "polluting" to a few specific ones, instead of many generic ones that will conflict down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But now i have 3 answer. How i know wich one was first to accept that one as an Answer? If I sort by oldest, the oldest is on the top or the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it almost right.

Do like this:

```
.note { /*common style*/}
.note:before { /*common style*/ }
.note-topLeft:before {border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;}
.note-topRight:before {border-width: 0 0 16px 16px;}
.note-bottomLeft:before {border-width: 16px 16px 0 0;}
.note-bottomRight:before {border-width: 16px 0 0 16px;}
```

And then:

```
<div id="infoPopup" class="note note-topLeft"><div id="thing">Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div id="infoPopup1" class="note note-topRight"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div id="infoPopup2" class="note note-bottomLeft"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div id="infoPopup3" class="note note-bottomRight"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
```

`1, 2, 3` Do not use the same `id` twice.

Comment: Adding on to what @leo said: If all the things originally labelled `id="infoPopup"` have a shared "infoPopup" style, change infoPopup to a class, and write `class="infoPopup note …"` (styled with `.infoPopup {}`). And if all "infoPopup"s are also `.note`, drop "infoPopup" entirely and put its styles in `.note`. (And taking a step back: no offense if you know this already, but you aren't required to specify an id)

Comment: Yes, i understand the id was a mistake. At that stage i just did a copy / paste to test each of my style. I will just use one id and change the class.

Answer (score 3):

the positions are different in each one (not just the border-width)

```css
.note {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    color: #fff;
    background: #97C02F;
}

.note:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #658E15 #fff;
}

.noteTopRight:before {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
}

.noteTopLeft:before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 16px 16px;
}

.noteBottomRight:before {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-width: 16px 16px 0 0;
}

.noteBottomLeft:before {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-width: 16px 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="note noteTopRight"><div id="thing">Hola<br/> World</div></div>
<div class="note noteTopLeft"><div>Hola<br/> World</div></div>
<div class="note noteBottomRight"><div>Hola<br/> World</div></div>
<div class="note noteBottomLeft"><div>Hola<br/> World</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment above, I would simplify it like this:

```css
 .note{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    color: #fff;
    background: #97C02F;
}

.note:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #658E15 #fff;
}


.noteTopLeft:before {
    border-width: 0 0 16px 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

.noteTopRight:before {
    border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.noteBottomRight:before {
    border-width: 16px 16px 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.noteBottomLeft:before {
    border-width: 16px 0 0 16px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="infoPopup0" class="note noteTopRight"><div id="thing">Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div id="infoPopup1" class="note noteTopLeft"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div id="infoPopup2" class="note noteBottomRight"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
<div id="infoPopup3" class="note noteBottomLeft"><div>Hola<br> World</div></div>
```